# VS.2017 cannot add project to TFS Source Control

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

Visual Studio 2017 has been the crappiest so far. I have an existing solution that I want to add to source control (VisualStudioOnline.com) but every time I do it simply creates a GIT repository locally and I DO NOT want GIT. It does not even ask.

I changed the options to default to VisualStudioOnline. But when I try to add the solution I select Manage Connections, then I see the project repository I created on VSO website and click on it then Connect. After a while the window simply disappears giving no error and the Team Explorer still says I am Offline, so it was not added to TFS. My VS.2017 however is connected to my VSO account.

What is the problem here? can't they even give a hint as to why it is not connecting?

Comment: Try to refer to these steps and check the result: 1. Open Team explorer and connect to your TFVC team project 2. Create a new folder (e.g. D:\Project) 3.Click File > New > Project to create a new project in D:\Project 4. Right click the solution >Add to source control

Comment: I agree with the OPs frustration It should be seamless and without a hint. I was facing the same issue and was frustrated setting the Source Control under Tools to "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" and getting a git repo while adding the files to source control. It should ask which source control the user wants to use. Why to default to git?

Answer (score 5):

So you want to add project to **TFVC** VCS not git in VSTS (visual studio team services). First you should create a TFVC repo on VSTS, then connect with VS2017, finally add the existing project in source control and check in. Detail steps as below:

1. Create a TFVC repo by creating a new project or adding a new repo for existing project in VSTS.

   [image][image]
2. Connect with VS2017.

   VS -> Team explorer -> Manage connections -> connect to project -> make sure your email for VSTS acount is selected -> select your new created TFVC repo -> connect -> Map & Get.
   [image]

   [image] [image]
3. Add the existing project to source control.

   Copy the project file to the subfolder that you just mapped -> Team explorer -> source control explorer -> select the folder with the TFVC repo you created -> click **Add Items to Folder** -> select the project -> Finish.

   [image]
4. Check in changes to VSTS.

   Now the project is added in source control, you can click **pending changes** to **check in** the project to VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not intuitive and I hate it too. These are the most "automated" steps:

1. Open the solution you want to add to VSTS.
2. Go to Team->Manage connections...
3. You will see all your VSTS connections, I happen to use two VSTS, one from visualstudio.com and one on-premises. **Choose the connection you want and right-click then select connect.**
4. Once connected, select File->Source Control->Add solution to source control...
5. It will show up the VSTS dialog and let you choose a folder for your solution.
6. Done.

Cheers,

MarianoC